# I have a Macbook Pro 2012 that continues to beach ball after I erased the hard drive and upgraded to macOS Sierra 10.12 , why is still beach balling?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, software-update

My original OS is 10.10.5. I had trouble with really bad beach balling. I ran an Malware bytes scan, everything is good. I ran disk permissions in Disk Utility with a total of two repairs and verified after each repair. Verified a total of three times. Prior to verifiying it a third time I received a cksum error on both repairs. I erased the hard drive anyways because it was still beach balling and it went from 10.10.5 to 10.8. I ran an upgrade that took at least 12 hours to complete. It rebooted and it stilled continued to beach ball after the upgrade install. SMART status is verified so I'm assuming the hard drive is good.

Comment: What's the SMART status of the disk? Have you tried repairing disk and permissions? (All of this can be found in disk utility)

Comment: I've repaired the disk and verified it twice. Received a cksum error both times and verified it a third time after I erased it. Didn't receive any errors after

Comment: SMART status is Verified

Comment: Actual question is correct. After I erased the hard drive the OS went to 10.8. The original OS is 10.10.5. The upgrade was for macOC Sierra 10.12

Comment: Have you tried running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)?  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: Not yet. I will first thing in the morning when I'm back to the laptop. I'm thinking it can be faulty SATA cables from the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the 13" MacBook Pro 2012, Disk Utility is not indicating a failing hard drive via its SMART status, and that the OS and/or any software you are running is not the cause there is one other thing I've not seen you mention you need to check into.

This model MBP13 2012 can develop an issue with the flex cable that connects the hard drive to the rest of the computer if the unit is getting carried around in a back pack or heavy book bag. The cable can be damaged by compression of the bottom case in the area where the cable runs from the hard drive to the logic board causing errors in the integrity of the data flowing to and from the hard drive.

Check out Apple's website but for this model they may still be offering to replace that cable at no cost for the 2012 only. If you've never had the hard drive flex cable replaced then all things being equal that may actually be the cause. Failure of this cable/bracket assembly starts as a general slowdown of even the simplest things on the computer like just opening a folder full of files. Best of luck with it.

Comment: For clarity purposes when you say flex cables you're talking about the hard drives SATA cables right ?

Comment: If you take it to any Apple Genius Bar they will know better what you are talking about if you just say hard drive flex cable. Remember these folks are less and less technicians now. SATA might confuse them.

Comment: Yea that makes sense